# Get buttons already added in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a simple 15-puzzle game. I added 16 generated numbered buttons to a JFrame and that was the exercise (University). 
I'm now trying to go further and make interactions so I need to get all buttons and put them into a 2D vector in order to calculate where user clicks and if and where the cell could "slide", but I don't know how to get them from the Frame.

Here is the generator code:

```
public void generation(){
    int num;
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < this.getTot(); i++)
        list.add(""+ i);

    while(!list.isEmpty()){
        do{                     
            num = rand.nextInt(this.getTot());
        } while (!list.contains("" + num));

        list.remove("" + num);

        if(num == 0){
            this.add(new Button(" ");
        }
        else{
            this.add(new Button("" + num);                  
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the constructor:

```
public Base15(int x, int y){
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y));

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.generation();
    this.cells = new Button[x][y];  
}
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: Followed ufis suggestions and had the 2d array done!

```
for (int row = 0; row < x; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < y; col++){
            do{                     
                num = rand.nextInt(this.getTot());
            } while (!list.contains("" + num));

            list.remove("" + num);

            if(num == 0){
                cells[row][col] = new Button(" ", sw, label);
                this.add(cells[row][col]);

            }else{
                cells[row][col] = new Button("" + num, sw, label);
                this.add(cells[row][col]);

            }
        }
```

Thank you all!

Comment: y not bind a action performed event on each of the Button, and you need to make the `Button` as member field.

Comment: "Button" is my class extended from JButton and I've already put an ActionListener inside.

Comment: So what you asking for is how to know cell action and whether a cell could move?

Comment: I think there two way to achieve the first goal: 1. add `action` fields for each button, and use only `actionListener`. another method is use `actionListener` for each button. thus you can detect which button are clicked

Comment: as for slideable, I think you can have a simple calculation for this, to compute whether space around a button is filled with another button, if one of the cell around is empty, then return true. else false

Comment: Yes, the first goal is achieved, I have an ActionListener on every button and I know what is pressed. I thought that, in order to know if  and how many cells can move, I could put all buttons in a 2d-vector, but I don't know how, since there is no method to get them from frame.

Comment: y get them from frame? you could just get them logically, into a array `Button[][]`, then everything is easier!

Comment: Look at my generation code. I cannot get the randomly generated button into an array because of the structure of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I completely misunderstand your question you can do

```
JFrame theFrame = new JFrame();
// lots of code here to add buttons
Component[] components = theFrame.getComponents();
for (Component component : components) {
    if (component instanceof Button) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But it would be better if you store some reference to all your Buttons as you create / add them to the Frame.

---

***EDIT:***
I think you should check the way you create your `Button`s when you add them to the frame.

When you do

```
JFrame theFrame = new JFrame();

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    theFrame.add(new Button());
}
```

You have no reference to your `Button`s. This is why you need to "get the `Button`s from the Frame.

If you do something like

```
JFrame theFrame = new JFrame();
Button[] buttons = new Button[15];

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new Button();
    theFrame.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

You will not have to loop through all the components at a later stage, because you have reference to the buttons in your buttons array. You can of course make that a `Button[][]` too. But the win here is that you have the reference to the list of buttons at creation time.

Comment: I think we are on the right track, but I still think I need a multi-dim array, because cells can be moved left, right, up and down and I need to know where I can slide them.

Comment: You can also (since `Button` if your own class) put a x and y attribute in your `Button` class to store the co-ordinate in the grid. There are many ways to achieve the functionality of storing/referring to them as grid structure. **I think what you do need is to keep reference to your `Button`s as you create them.** I will update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some suggestions on your creation of your `Button` objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void resetPanel(JFrame form)
{
    Component[] components = form.getContentPane().getComponents();  
    for(Component component : components)
    {
        if(component instanceof JButton){

            JButton button = (JButton) component;
            button.setText("?");


        }
    }
}
```